# Error installing gcc 3.0.1 for x86-64 architecture

Tags: gcc, x86-64

I'm trying to compile the gcc 3.0.1 files. When I use `configure`, it gives an error with the following message

> Configuration x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu not supported

Comment: you don't install application for an architecture but a platform. But what's your platform? Windows? Linux?... And why are you using such an ancient gcc version?

Comment: My platform is linux, I'm using Debian. I have trying to install to do some testing.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what was special about GCC 3.0.1 that you needed to use it?

Comment: It's no big deal, I wanted to see the assembly-generated code and make a comparison to the generated gcc code 6, rsrs

Comment: gcc 7 and 8 made some significant improvements to code-gen, e.g. load/store coalescing for narrow adjacent stores/loads, including but not limited to struct members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC 3.0 did not support the x86-64 architecture, it is too old for that.  The x86-64 target was added in [GCC 3.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.1/changes.html):

> #### New Targets and Target Specific Improvements
>
> […]
>
> - The x86 back end has had some noticeable work done to it.
>
>   - SuSE Labs developers Jan Hubicka, Bo Thorsen and Andreas Jaeger have contributed a port to the AMD x86-64 architecture.